# How can I find all the correct combinations?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinations

There will be an *array* and a *number*.

I want to get all possible combinations from the *array* by number.
I mean if the array is [2,4,1,3,0,1] and the number is 5,
then the result will be [2,3] [4,1] [2,3,0] [4,1,0] [1,3,1,0].

So, I try this algorithm

```js
function solution(arr, n) {
  let result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
       let sum = arr[i] + arr[j]
       if(sum === n) {
           result.push([arr[i], arr[j]])
       }
    }
  }
  return  result
}
```

But, this algorithm is only for two combinations.
I have been thinking how to do three combinations and four combinations during the last five hours.

What is the way to access it to solve that?

Comment: Sounds like the infamous **subset sum problem**.

Comment: The simple brute force approach is to iterate over all 2^N possible combinations and check the sum.

Comment: Will there only be positive numbers in the array?

Comment: @RickardElimää: there is a zero in the sample.

Comment: OK, I rephrase the question. :) Will there be negative numbers in the array?

Comment: Here is a Google Coding Interview, on this subject, that may be of interest: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKu_SEDAykw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something simple and naive:

```js
const sumsTo = ([n, ...ns], t) =>
  n === undefined ? [] : [                         // if list is empty, no results
    ... (n === t ? [[n]] : []),                    // if n == t, include [n]
    ... sumsTo (ns, t - n) .map (s => [n, ...s]),  // include n and recur
    ... sumsTo (ns, t)                             // skip n and recur
  ]

console .log (
  sumsTo ([2, 4, 1, 3, 0, 1], 5)
  /* display */ .map (JSON.stringify) .join ('\n')
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here we use a fairly simple recursion, always reducing the list of numbers to test and sometimes reducing the total we're seeking.

It will repeat arrays, for instance in this example, `[4, 1]`.  If you want to remove duplicates, then we can just run a uniqueness function (such as `const uniq = (xs) => [...new Set(xs)]`) on the result.

The performance is likely to be terrible, but then it seems likely that no algorithm here will have great performance.

Answer (score 0):

One elegant way to solve the problem is with a slightly modified k-combinatorial algorithm.

I don't know enough JavaScript to write it in your native language, but here is a Python implementation that I hope will suffice as well as pseudo-code:

```py
def find_combination(input, value):
    """Find all combination in input which it's sum is equal to value and has minimum of two elements."""
    
    for k in range(2, len(input) + 1):
        result = gen_combination(input, k, value)
        for x in result:
            print(x)


def gen_combination(input, k, value):
    """Returns unique combinations of k-value from input which it's sum equal to value."""

    output = []
    _gen_combination_rec(input, output, k, value)
    return output


def _gen_combination_rec(array, output, k, value, index=0, data=None):
    """Recursively traverse input to find combinations of k-value."""

    if data == None:
        data = [0] * k

    if index == k:
        sd = sorted(data)
        if sd not in output and sum(data) == value:
            output.append(sd)
        data[index - 1] = 0
        return

    i = 0
    n = len(array)
    while i < n and index < k:
        data[index] = array[i]
        _gen_combination_rec(array[i + 1 :], output, k, value, index + 1, data)
        i += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = [2, 4, 1, 0, 3, 1]
    find_combination(input, 5)
```

Here is the output of the above code when run from a terminal:

```sh
$ python main.py 
[2, 3]
[1, 4]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 4]
[1, 1, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 3]
```

Comment: [I have translated your algorithm to JavaScript](https://jsbin.com/xajiwuloci/1/edit?js,console). The only major difference would be that JS doesn't have a good equivalent of `sd in data`. I created `isIn()` but it's as simple as possible. It might not be efficient as it has to re-scan the arrays every time. It can be improved but I'd leave as an exercise to other people, since there are multiple optimisation paths to take and I don't want to commit to one.